# Is it possible to import another Chrome user's profiles configuration into MY Chrome profiles?

Tags: google-chrome, export, profile

I have created a set of Chrome profiles that work well for me. The names, the accounts they access, etc.

In the spirit of not having to rewrite the wheel every time someone wants to do this for themselves, is it possible for me to export my profile configuration and provide that to another user so they can import the configuration... but obviously not with my data or account, just the profile names, etc.

I have not tried anything yet, until I get more information